# How to solve date and time problem in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, date, datepicker

I am using datepicker in magento form

This is my code:

```
$dateFormatIso = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);
        $fieldset->addField('created_at', 'date', array(
        'name'   => 'created_at',
        'label'  => Mage::helper('example)->__('Created At'),
        'title'  => Mage::helper('example')->__('Created At'),
        'image'  => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
        'format'       => $dateFormatIso,
        'time' => true
    ));
```

But in frontend same date is not display

[image]

At front end

[image]

This code is use to display date in frontend

```
<?php echo $this->formatDate($val->getCreatedAt(), 'medium', true) ;?>
```

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-date-format/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  of question is too old

Comment: Since when is "too old" an off topic reason? Anyways, I'm voting to close because it's unclear. I can only guess that it's about a timezone problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this one. It worked for me.

`Mage::app()->getLocale()->date($val->getCreatedAt(), Zend_Date::DATE_SHORT, null, false);`

best of luck.

Comment: this error occured    **Unable to parse date '2015-03-10 02:52:00' using 'M/d/yy' (M <> y)";i:1;s**

Comment: Which region date format you are using?

Comment: Eastern standard time (America/New_York)

Comment: Please try with this datefromat for admin grid and add/edit block: $dateFormatIso = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' and frontend use your code. I think it's admin time issue.

Comment: not working....